# Running shell commands from Xcode breakpoint

Tags: xcode, shell, breakpoints

I'm trying to run a shell script from a breakpoint in Xcode 4.5 DP 3. I set the breakpoint as such using the Choose button.

[image: Shell script command]

However, upon hitting the breakpoint I get the following message:

```
Error in shell command for breakpoint "(selector name)". The command "/Users/Max/Developer/saveToLog.sh" does not exist.
```

I've tried to put regular shell commands, like "say test" but Xcode prints the same message (with a different command name, of course). The shell script works fine when I run it from terminal.

Comment: Have you tried set permissions? Eg. `chmod +x saveToLog.sh`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, first check to make sure you have the shell permissions set correctly. In terminal type:

```
chmod u+x saveToLog.sh
```

And I would also locate the shell script inside the project folder (didn't seem to work correctly for me when the script was located on my desktop).

This is the script I tested on:

```
#!/bin/bash 
touch ~/Desktop/ItWorks.txt 
echo "This actually works!" > ~/Desktop/ItWorks.txt
```

Comment: No dice -- I added the shell script to my app target, but when I hit the breakpoint I get: `Xcode[907:203] *** NSTask: Task create for path '/Users/Max/Developer/iphone/HeyZap/appendToLog.sh' failed: 22, "Invalid argument".  Terminating temporary process.` regardless of the contents of the script

Comment: Try running it with out the argument with the script I added to the answer

Comment: Thanks Brendt! I was missing the #!/bin/bash line to make it work. Have a good day, Max

Comment: No worries Max, glad to have helped! Have a great day also :)